# Create 2 light red/green

Tags: arduino, irobot-create, battery

I am working on a project with the Create 2. Just recently I have run into a problem with the battery state. The Create 2 has been charging all night so its clean light shows green. However, when I unplug it and press the clean button, it shows red and will not consistently run commands from my Arduino that I have hooked up to it.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How old is your robot / battery?

Comment: Not quite the same issue, but take a look at my answer to [iRobot Create: Making Noise and Flashing Red Light While Charging](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/irobot-create-making-noise-and-flashing-red-light-while-charging/9207#9207). As Ben implies, it sounds like the battery is dead or dying...

Comment: Check what the battery charge is when "fully charged" via OI sensor packet 25.
Also try resetting the robot and letting it charge again.

Answer (score 1):

Red means that your battery is either truly dead, or the Create mistakenly thinks it is. To figure out which it is:

1. Remove the battery and put it back in after about 30 seconds.
2. Run the motors (you can just press Clean to start a demo) until the battery is fully drained.
3. Charge it overnight.

At this point the battery's true state should be reflected in the LED color. If it's still red, then you will need a new battery.